# Как оптимизировать написанную вручную функцию intersection на python? Не прохожу тест по времени

Tags: python-3.5

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))


def intersection(a, b):
    c = []
    i, j = 0, 0

    while i != len(a):
        if a[i] < b[j]:
            i += 1
        elif a[i] >= b[j]:
            while j != len(b):
                if a[i] == b[j]:
                    c.append(a[i])
                    i += 1
                    break
                else:
                    j += 1
            else:
                i += 1
                j = 0
    return c


print(*intersection(a, b))
```

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу задание, никто не будет разбирать ваш код, чтобы понять суть задачи.

Comment: Тут не столько тест по времени, сколько сам алгоритм неверен. Например, для списков [3, 4] и [5,3] он у Вас ничего не найдет. Подсказка - сортировка списка - n*log(n), что меньше Вашей квадратичной сложности.